# How to wait for remote validation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, validation

I have created a form validation plugin just like [jQuery Validation Plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/)

But I have no idea how to wait for remote validations like check for duplicate usernames

jQuery Validation Plugin:

```
var form = $('form');

form.validate();

if (form.valid()) {
  //Do something if the form is valid
}
```

My Validation Plugin:

```
var form = $('form');

if (await form.valid()) {
  //Do something if the form is valid
}
```

I don't like to use async and await operators and I would like to know how the [jQuery Validation Plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) does this without using async and await operators

Comment: The Plugin uses jQuery's [ajax method](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) which is just a wrapper around [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest).

Comment: This is true, but how we do not need to use await when validating using jQuery Validation Plugin

Comment: Because they don't use a promise-based approach like fetch(). You can read about the differences [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not because of not using await/async, it is because of how it is implemented

In fact, there is no other option